# path variables in Cypress

Tags: javascript, cypress

With Postman I can use path variables to create a correct URL, but is there a possibility with Cypress? I have seen the qs method they mentioned but nothing on path variables.
I want to extend my base-url with `/something/somethingelse`

Thanks.

Comment: Are you using `cy.intercept()` or `cy.request()` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to extend the to url with some dynamic values, you can do something like:

1.Go to `cypress/support/commands.js` and create a custom command.

```
Cypress.Commands.add('requestOne', (value) => {
    cy.request({
        url: `https://example.com/api/${value}`,
        method: 'GET'
    }).then(response => {
        //Do Something with response
    })
})
```

2.In your tests You can just pass the value in the paramters.

```
cy.requestOne('something/somethingelse')
```